# Attach file to blank email in Mail.app from my cocoa app

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, email, attachment

My requirement is simple. Launch Mail.app and create a blank email and attach a file/files.

I've seen NSWorkspace to actually launch mail, but how can I effectively mimic the same functionality when you drag a file to the mail icon? Googled to death but always get Cocoa Touch results!

Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: Yeah, what he said.  You want to look up NSAppleScript and NSAppleEventDescriptor, and "Cocoa Scripting Guide."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works fine:

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openFile:@"/path/to/file/file.ext" withApplication:@"Mail"];
```